# proportion table for multiple variables

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am trying to create relative frequencies for continuous variables grouped by a factor and year. My minimial code is below. factor1 has 3 levels, and year stretches over multiple years. Each of the continuous variables is a total grouped by factor1 and years.

```
factor1<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
years<-c(2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001)
continuous1<-seq(50,300,50)
continuous2<-seq(50,300,50)
continuous3<-seq(50,300,50)
continuous4<-seq(50,300,50)
df<-cbind(years,factor2,continuous1,continuous2,continuous3,continuous4)
```

I would have something like this output:

```
factor1 years continuous1 continuous2 continuous3 continuous4
  1    2000       0.166         0.166    0.166        0.166
  2    2000       0.333         0.333    0.333        0.333
  3    2000       0.5           0.5      0.5          0.5
  1    2001       0.266         0.266    0.266        0.266
  2    2001       0.333         0.333    0.333        0.333
  3    2001       0.4           0.4      0.4          0.4
```

Any advice or recommendations you can provide will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `cbind` will create a matrix here, not a data frame. To do that, use `data.frame` (or a fancy variant like `tibble::tibble` or `data.table::data.table`, if you like). Also, what you're calling factors are numbers, not factors, so a different name would be a good idea.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what the output should look like? Not totally sure how you want the proportions displayed. Thanks :)

Comment: something like this ? `df <- as.data.frame(df);by(df[-1:-2],df[1:2],prop.table)`

Comment: or this maybe: `df <- as.data.frame(df);cbind(df[1:2], prop.table(df[-1:-2]))`

Comment: OK so what's the difference between what you want and what you get by making a function out of what you put for the desired output or what you had so far in dplyr?

Comment: Sorry all, I've updated the question with the output I am looking for

Comment: Based on the editions in your question, it seems that your trouble is more in how to calculate the frequencies than in how to generate the table. If you figure that, than applying the formula to each variable by group will be easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll prefer to use `dplyr::mutate_at` to achieve a solution since all the 4 columns has got similarity in names. The `dplyr` based solution will be something like:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(years) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("continuous")), funs(./sum(.)))

# # A tibble: 6 x 6
# # Groups: years [2]
#   years factor1 continuous1 continuous2 continuous3 continuous4
#   <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1  2000    1.00       0.167       0.167       0.167       0.167
# 2  2000    2.00       0.333       0.333       0.333       0.333
# 3  2000    3.00       0.500       0.500       0.500       0.500
# 4  2001    1.00       0.267       0.267       0.267       0.267
# 5  2001    2.00       0.333       0.333       0.333       0.333
# 6  2001    3.00       0.400       0.400       0.400       0.400
```

**Note:** I have modified OP's data.frame creation steps and changed `cbind` with `data.frame`

**Data:** Content is same as one used by OP.

```
factor1<-c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
years<-c(2000,2000,2000,2001,2001,2001)
continuous1<-seq(50,300,50)
continuous2<-seq(50,300,50)
continuous3<-seq(50,300,50)
continuous4<-seq(50,300,50)
#df<-cbind(years,factor1,continuous1,continuous2,continuous3,continuous4)
# Used data.frame to create a data.frame instead of a matrix
df<-data.frame(years,factor1,continuous1,continuous2,continuous3,continuous4)
```

Comment: Thank you, MKR! This was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, but here's something to put you in a possible way using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- as.data.table(df)

> dt[ , lapply( .SD, function(x) sum(x)/.N ), by = .(factor1, factor2) ]
   factor1 factor2 continuous1 continuous2 continuous3 continuous4
1:       1    2000          50          50          50          50
2:       2    2000         100         100         100         100
3:       3    2000         150         150         150         150
4:       1    2001         200         200         200         200
5:       2    2001         250         250         250         250
6:       3    2001         300         300         300         300
```

Take a look in the output of the individual components to understand what's happening:

```
dt[ , lapply(.SD, sum), by = .(factor1, factor2) ]
dt[ , .N, by = .(factor1, factor2) ]
```

Change the formula according to your needs. If you want a more specific answer, update your question with a better example, a better description of what you want to compute and an example of the desired output.

Comment: I've updated the question with my desired output, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: How are you calculating the frequencies? How did you go from 50 to 0.166, 200 to 0.266, 300 to 0.4? It's the sum of the values per year and factor divided by the correspondent factor value? Or by the number of occurrences? Figure that, then change the formula inside the function.